# How to get the last item of array after using split in pnp modern search results webpart v4

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnpjs, microsoft, pnp-search-webparts

I am using PNP modern search v4 webparts, i was trying to modify the search results view, where i need to show the last item of array below is the sample code which is  not working.

```
{{#with (split (slot item @root.slots.Topic) ':')}} 
    {{[this.length - 1]}}
 {{/with}}
```

please can anyone guide me how i can get the last item dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `last` helper function to get the last item of an array.

```
{{#with (split (slot item @root.slots.Topic) ':')}} 
    {{last this}}
{{/with}}
```